# Doubt in StackWalker code

Tags: winapi

Here is the project page
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx

```
[STACKFRAME64][1] s;

//s contains the current stack frame filled by calling [StackWalk64][2] WinAPI

if (s.AddrPC.Offset == s.AddrReturn.Offset)
{
  printf("StackWalk64-Endless-Callstack!");
}
```

My question is when will this condition be satisfied? What addresses do s.AddrPC.Offset, s.AddrReturn.Offset contain?
Is the return address in the last frame on stack = 0?

Comment: Oops! I think you misspelled StackWalker in your title.

Comment: Oh whoops, I forgot I can do that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully never, but it is a basic sanity check in case the stack frame got stomped.  Which isn't unlikely when you try to walk the stack in an exception handler triggered by a nasty hardware exception like AccessViolation.  Without that check the code would enter an endless loop, constantly finding the same stack frame back.

AddrPC is the address of the call instruction, AddrReturn is the return address, the address of the previous call instruction (+5).  Not sure what "stack 0" might mean.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for replying. I was asking if the bottommost frame of stack has a return address of 0?

Comment: @Hans: Say we have the stack like |A|B| with a being the top of stack. AddrPC will point to the first instruction of A and AddrReturn will point to the return address inside B?

Comment: AddrPC is the address of the current instruction in A.  Wherever it happened to be when the thread got suspended, rarely the first instruction.  AddrReturn points to B, the instruction after the call to A.

Comment: What address will IMAGEHLP_LINE64.Address and IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64.Address contain if I pass s.AddrPC.Offset to SymGetLineFromAddr64() and SymGetSymFromAddr64() respectively?

Comment: I got the following in a log file AddrPC : 4241369 , Function Name : Func5 , Full filename with path : c:\xxxx\stackwalker\main.cpp , Line number : 31 , Module name  :StackWalker , loadedImageName : C:\xxxx\xxxx\WIN2000_DEBUG\StackWalker.exe
Base address of module : 4194304
IMAGEHLP_LINE64.Address : 4241296
IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64 : 4241296

Comment: I want to know what these addresses point to : IMAGEHLP_LINE64.Address and IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64.Address?

Comment: Does StackWalk64() automatically keep returning frames until we reach end of stack if we run it in a loop?

Comment: Here is another frame AddrPC : 2002432968 , Function Name : RtlInitializeExceptionChain , Full filename with path :  , Line number : 0 , Module name  :ntdll , loadedImageName : C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Base address of module : 2002059264
IMAGEHLP_LINE64.Address : 4277695
IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64.Address : 2002432914. How come AddrPC is 40 bits?