# Attaching MSVC 2012 profiler hangs the application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiler

I have a `C++` application (it's built using `Qt 5.8` library and works with `PostgreSQL 9.5` database in case it's relevant). The application is build by `MSVC 2012` compiler, is 64-bit application and both debug and release versions run normally on their own and under cdb debugger.

When I try to profile the running application by `Visual Studio` instrument (Analyze -> Profiler -> Attach), it seemingly hangs as soon as it tries to do something meaningful: simply resizing a window or clicking on checkboxes works, but any attempt to compute new values and write them to database never succeeds, as if control flow didn't return from some call.

When I stop the profiling, Studio marks as a "hot path" sequence of calls `RtlWalkFrameChain`->`RtlpWalkFrameChain`->`RtlpLookupFunctionEntryForStackWalks`->`RtlLookupFunctionTable`->`RtlAcquireSRWLockShared`.
`RtlpWalkFrameChain` has the biggest "exclusive samples" count.
Trying to filter data to exclude initial several seconds of run (until the apparent freeze) results in "No Call Tree Data Is Available" message.

I didn't manage to find any article or post with a similar problem.
The project is build in Qt Creator (I don't have a project file Studio would understand, so I can't run "normal" performance analysis).
OS is `Windows 7`, exact version of `Visual Studio` is 11.0.61219.00 Update 5.
Any idea on the subject would be welcome.

**Upd:** When I try to profile the application with Luke Stackwalker profiler, it aborts with the message `ERROR: StackWalk64-Endless-Callstack!`. The only relevant comment about the message I found is [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563321/doubt-in-stackwalker-code). When I run application under `cdb` debugger and then try to profile it with Luke Stackwalker, the error message is the same, but subsequent pause in the debugger shows the proper (or at least believable) stack for all threads. For the working thread debugger points to a line of code inside system library and doesn't advance no matter what I do (once again, without profiling attempts the application runs normally, debugger or not).

Comment: Without a test case to reproduce your issue, we are helpless. This is probably an edge case combining VS Analyzer, your program and the current Ntdll version you have on your system. Can your at least provide an exe ?